# What is the difference between calling setSoLinger with a 0 value and not enabling soLinger at all?

Tags: java, sockets

In Java, is there a difference between setting a socket with Socket.setSoLinger(true, 0) and not calling setSoLinger at all? Is there a difference in how the socket is closed?

I have looked through the Java sources, and I don't see anything special around socket closes with regards to soLinger. This leads me to believe this is an OS specific behavior. In my case I am working on Linux.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922951/java-network-server-and-time-wait & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490196/tcp-connection-in-time-wait-wont-allow-reconnect-java

Answer (score 3):

When a timeout is specified via `setSoLinger()`, `close()` blocks until the closing hand-shake is completed, or until the specified amount of time passes.

However, `close()` provides no indication that the closing handshake failed to complete, even
if the time limit set by `setSoLinger()` expires before the closing sequence completes.

In other
words, `setSoLinger()` does not provide any additional assurance to the application in current
implementations.

[Here's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123742552) the source of info.

Answer (score 3):

`Socket.setSoLinger(true, 0)` is actually the default, so there is no difference whatsoever. However see also Zaki's answer for why even a non-zero value is futile anyway in Java. `Socket.close()` ignores the `errno` that is generated if the timeout expires. I pointed out this problem about ten years ago and got the reply that it couldn't be changed for backward compatibility reasons. I don't agree actually, but there you go. However the NIO2 stuff in Java 7 does recognize this case and throw an exception properly.